# Spring Security OAuth2 ResourceServer: Allow Unauthenticated Access if Token Absent?

Tags: spring-security

I'm planning to use Spring Security's OAuth2 ResourceServer to secure my services. However, due to certain release schedules, I cannot block access requests without a token. I'm wondering if it's possible to authenticate when a token is present and allow unauthenticated access when no token is provided?

I've attempted to customize the Authenticator to return a default usernamepassword identity for unauthenticated requests, but it doesn't seem to be effective.

Im using reactive stack.

Finally, I used multiple security matchers, and this approach worked.

```
@Bean
public SecurityWebFilterChain oauthSecurityWebFilterChain(ServerHttpSecurity http) {
    http
        .securityMatcher(exchange -> exchange.getRequest().getHeaders().containsKey(HttpHeaders.AUTHORIZATION) ?
            ServerWebExchangeMatcher.MatchResult.match() :
            ServerWebExchangeMatcher.MatchResult.notMatch()
        )
        .csrf(ServerHttpSecurity.CsrfSpec::disable)
        .cors(Customizer.withDefaults())
        .logout(ServerHttpSecurity.LogoutSpec::disable)
        .authorizeExchange(
            authorizeExchangeSpec -> authorizeExchangeSpec
                .pathMatchers("/api/*/app/**").authenticated()
                .pathMatchers("/api/*/admin/**").authenticated()
                .pathMatchers("/api/*/apps/**").authenticated()
                .pathMatchers(HttpMethod.GET, "/api/v1/assets/firmware/**").permitAll()
                .anyExchange().permitAll()
        )
        .oauth2ResourceServer(e -> e.jwt(Customizer.withDefaults()))
        .securityContextRepository(NoOpServerSecurityContextRepository.getInstance());

    return http.build();
}

/**
 * 无需认证的 SecurityWebFilterChain
 * <p>
 * 兼容未添加认证的应用，后续移除
 *
 * @param http http
 * @return SecurityWebFilterChain
 */
@Bean
public SecurityWebFilterChain noAuthSecurityWebFilterChain(ServerHttpSecurity http) {
    http
        .securityMatcher(exchange -> exchange.getRequest().getHeaders().containsKey(HttpHeaders.AUTHORIZATION) ?
            ServerWebExchangeMatcher.MatchResult.notMatch() :
            ServerWebExchangeMatcher.MatchResult.match()
        )
        .csrf(ServerHttpSecurity.CsrfSpec::disable)
        .cors(Customizer.withDefaults())
        .logout(ServerHttpSecurity.LogoutSpec::disable)
        .authorizeExchange(
            authorizeExchangeSpec -> authorizeExchangeSpec
                .anyExchange().permitAll()
        );

    return http.build();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You just set all path with `permitAll()` in a `SecurityFilterChain` with `oauth2ResourceServer`.

Request will be allowed if anonymous or if authorized with a valid Bearer token (but if token is invalid, then 401 will be returned).